# Проверить, сбросил ли пользователь соединение

Tags: python, http, asyncio, sanic

Пользователь запрашивает данные, и ждет какое-то время, пока подготавливаются данные на сервере. Вдруг происходит ситуация, что пользователь сбрасывает соединение. Вдруг у него пропадает интернет или еще что, как отловить это программно?

Comment: Если требуется можно просто пинговать клиента. Создайте запрос которым будут меняться клиент-сервер каждые 30 секунд например. Если нет ответа то дисконект. Обмен идет по TCP или UDP?

Comment: Судя по меткам речь о http запросе и проверке не отвалилось ли существующее соединение пока генерируется ответ на запрос. Тут ping не поможет никак. Видимо, автор ищет специфичный для sanic способ узнать, живое ли еще соединение (sanic изолирует приложение от работы с сетевыми соединениями).

Comment: поддерживать постоянное соединение и как отвалится - отлавливать. вебсокет в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Должно сработать [connection_lost](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/fc4b7df088fc78d74ad9ab8061500c9d5e5d9473/sanic/server.py#L218)

```
import asyncio
from sanic import Sanic, response

app = Sanic()

@app.route('/')
async def handler(request):
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print('Not OK') # отловили тут
        raise e
    return response.text('OK')

app.run()
```

Асинхронная задачка должна райзнуть asyncio.CancelledError, если работа приложения блокирующая - используй экзекутор.